# Do any tools exist to convert a OOP class into a SQL DB Schema?

Tags: sql, database, schema

Do any tools exist to convert a OOP class into a SQL DB Schema? This would be for languages like C#, Java, c++ etc..

How about the other way around, creating a class out of a DB Schema?

**EDIT:** I should have been more clear. I am wanting to know if there are tools that can generate a schema of an existing class or set of classes that have already been implemented as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) does both. This is for .NET code.

Here are a couple of videos:

- [Creating an Entity Data Model from a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff191186)
- [Creating an Entity Data Model the Model-First Way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff628199)

There are many tools that will generate a class (or set of classes) based on a table or set of tables and many that will do the opposite. They tend to be rather focused on a specific language and database.

There is also a whole class of frameworks that is designed as a go-between OOP code and databases, called [ORMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (Object Relational Mappers) - some of the better known ones are Hibernate (Java) and nHibernate (.NET).

Answer (score 0):

[Schema Export Tool](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Schema_generation) is one way how to generate a schema from types using NHibernate.

[S#arp architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/VSTemplatesAndCodeGen.ashx) provide tools for generating classes via T4 templates (Crud Scafold) from an existing database.